# Struggling to have Selenium select a button in a table (Python)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

continuing on my journey to build an bookerbot for fun. Here's the test website I'm using: https://www.barrys.com/schedule/castro/

I'm trying to book a session next Monday at 6:40 PM with the following code:

```
driver.get("https://www.barrys.com/schedule/castro/")
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//iframe[1]')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/main/article/nav/button[2]')
#this will select Monday's class
#Look at the child number, that is what determines the 6:40 class.
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);") 
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/main/article/div/table/tbody/tr[16]/td[3]/a'))).click()
```

The error I am getting is:

```
File "/Users/.../opt/anaconda3/envs/Bookerbot/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I noticed selenium times out in the past when they can't find the right element. Any ideas on what I could be missing here? I already factored in the iframe and also scrolled down as previously the bottom bar was hindering selection of the booking button.

Comment: Following line of your code is not performing any action `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/main/article/nav/button[2]')`